# Generate JSON file using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, json, html, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Web Development and just created a simple form in HTML and using some JavaScript I can submit the form by HTTP Post. I wanted to know whether there is a way to generate a JSON file with JSoN objects in it and then upload it to a JSON based database like firebase? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** yes, just use var `json = JSON.stringify(array);`

**Long answer:** You need an array, or better: an object array.
If you assign keys it will be much easier to work on serverside.
However just stringify the array and you are done.